# Firebase -How to loop through snapshot.hasChild("...")

Tags: ios, swift, loops, firebase-realtime-database

My database is laid out like below

```
users
  |
  @--uidABC
       |
       |---phone:"+13125550690"
       |
       |---followers
              |
              |----uid123
              |      |---timeStamp:111222
              |
              |----uid456
              |      |---timeStamp:777999
```

I use `.observeSingleEvent` to check to see if `uidABC` exists and if it does I want to check to see if there is a `child` named `followers` under that path.

I can use `snapshot.hasChild("followers")` to see if it's available and if it is **how can I loop through all the children underneath** `snapshot.hasChild("...")`?

I use the code below but it's looping through the wrong `snapshot`. It using the top level one when it should use whatever `DataSnapshot` is under `followers`

```
let ref = Database...child("users").child(uidABC)
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if !snapshot.exists() {

        // this user doesn't exist
        return
    }

    if !snapshot.hasChild("followers") {

       // this user exists but has no followers
       return
    }

    // this user exists and has followers now loop through them
    for uid in snapshot.children {

        let snapshot = uid as! DataSnapshot

        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
            let timeStamp = dict["timeStamp"] as? Double
            // eg. check for a specific timeStamp
         }
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39624171/4833705) and here

```
let ref = Database...child("users").child(uidABC)
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    if !snapshot.exists() {

        // this user doesn't exist
        return
    }

    if !snapshot.hasChild("followers") {

        // this user exists but has no followers
        return
    }

    // this user exists and has followers now loop through them
    let childSnapshot = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "followers") {

    for child in childSnapshot.children {

        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot

        let uid = snap.key

        if let dict = snap.value as? [String: Any] {

            let timeStamp = dict["timeStamp"] as? Double ?? 0
            // eg. check for a specific timeStamp
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `child`:

```
// this user exists and has followers now loop through them
for uid in snapshot.childSnapshot("followers") {

    guard let snapshot = uid as! DataSnapshot else {
     // Followers error
    }

    if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
        let timeStamp = dict["timeStamp"] as? Double
        // eg. check for a specific timeStamp
     }
 }
```

You can find more here: 
[Iterate over snapshot children in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341888/iterate-over-snapshot-children-in-firebase)

Comment: thanks I tried it but got an error -Value of type 'DataSnapshot' has no member 'child'; did you mean 'children'?

Comment: `child` was renamed to `childSnapshot(forPath: )` thanks for correcting me:) @LanceSamaria

Comment: I didn’t even I know I was correcting you. I thought you were closing an entirely different snapshot child property. Thanks for the assistance 